# Создание анимированной формы регистрации

Tags: php, ajax

Всем доброго времени суток! Сейчас занимаюсь разработкой сайта, и во время создания формы регистрации застряла...

Дело в том, что когда все поля проверены, и возвращается значение true, блок с формами регистрации должен плавно исчезать (`fadeOut`),а затем появляться (`fadeIn`) сообщение "Регистрация успешна", если были ошибки - поле с указанием ошибок. При верной регистрации, это echo просто выводит сверху значение true, вместо того что бы передать его.( причем вывод true осуществляется в красной рамке, как при ошибке), т.е. по существу submitHandler - не работает... Подскажите в чем проблема, буду бесконечно благодарна!

P.S. Все проверки работают, все сообщения выводит, в бд удачно все записывается. Не работает лишь выше описаная деталь.

```css
<?php
session_start(); 

  
 include("../include/db_connect.php");
 include("../functions/functions.php");
 
     $error = array();
         
        $login = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",strtolower(clear_string($_POST['reg_login']))); 
        $pass = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",strtolower(clear_string($_POST['reg_pass']))); 
        $surname = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_surname'])); 
        
        $name = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_name'])); 
        $patronymic = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_patronymic'])); 
        $email = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_email'])); 
        
        $phone = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_phone'])); 
        $address = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_address'])); 
 
 
    if (strlen($login) < 5 or strlen($login) > 15)
    {
       $error[] = "Логин должен быть от 5 до 15 символов!"; 
    }
    else
    {   
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM reg_user WHERE login = '$login'",$dbh);
    If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
       $error[] = "Логин занят!";
    }
            
    }
     
    if (strlen($pass) < 7 or strlen($pass) > 15) $error[] = "Укажите пароль от 7 до 15 символов!";
    if (strlen($surname) < 3 or strlen($surname) > 20) $error[] = "Укажите Фамилию от 3 до 20 символов!";
    if (strlen($name) < 3 or strlen($name) > 15) $error[] = "Укажите Имя от 3 до 15 символов!";
    if (strlen($patronymic) < 3 or strlen($patronymic) > 25) $error[] = "Укажите Отчество от 3 до 25 символов!";
    if (!preg_match("/^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_.]?[a-z0-9]+)?@[a-z0-9_.-]+(?:\.?[a-z0-9]+)?\.[a-z]{2,5})$/i",trim($email))) $error[] = "Укажите корректный email!";
    if (!$phone) $error[] = "Укажите номер телефона!";
    if (!$address) $error[] = "Необходимо указать адрес доставки!";
    
    if($_SESSION['img_captcha'] != strtolower($_POST['reg_captcha'])) $error[] = "Неверный код с картинки!";
    unset($_SESSION['img_captcha']);
    
   if (count($error))
   {
    
 echo implode('<br />',$error);
     
   }else
   {   
        $pass   = md5($pass);
        $pass   = strrev($pass);
        $pass   = "9nm2rv8q".$pass."2yo6z";
        
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  
  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO reg_user(login,pass,surname,name,patronymic,email,phone,address,datetime,ip)
      VALUES(
      
       '".$login."',
       '".$pass."',
       '".$surname."',
       '".$name."',
       '".$patronymic."',
                            '".$email."',
                            '".$phone."',
                            '".$address."',
                            NOW(),
                            '".$ip."'       
      )",$dbh);

 echo 'true';
}        
?>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
    include("include/db_connect.php");
    include("functions/functions.php");    
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="trackbar/trackbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/shop-script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./trackbar/jquery.trackbar.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#form_reg').validate(
    { 
     // правила для проверки
     rules:{
      "reg_login":{
       required:true,
       minlength:5,
                            maxlength:15,
                            remote: {
                            type: "post",    
                      url: "./reg/check_login.php"
                              }
      },
      "reg_pass":{
       required:true,
       minlength:7,
                            maxlength:15
      },
      "reg_surname":{
       required:true,
                            minlength:3,
                            maxlength:15
      },
      "reg_name":{
       required:true,
                            minlength:3,
                            maxlength:15
      },
      "reg_patronymic":{
       required:true,
                            minlength:3,
                            maxlength:25
      },
      "reg_email":{
          required:true,
       email:true
      },
      "reg_phone":{
       required:true
      },
      "reg_address":{
       required:true
      },
      "reg_captcha":{
       required:true,
                            remote: {
                            type: "post",    
                      url: "./reg/check_captcha.php"
                      
                              }
                            
      }
     },

     // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
     messages:{
      "reg_login":{
       required:"Укажите Логин!",
                            minlength:"От 5 до 15 символов!",
                            maxlength:"От 5 до 15 символов!",
                            remote: "Логин занят!"
      },
      "reg_pass":{
       required:"Укажите Пароль!",
                            minlength:"От 7 до 15 символов!",
                            maxlength:"От 7 до 15 символов!"
      },
      "reg_surname":{
       required:"Укажите вашу Фамилию!",
                            minlength:"От 3 до 20 символов!",
                            maxlength:"От 3 до 20 символов!"                            
      },
      "reg_name":{
       required:"Укажите ваше Имя!",
                            minlength:"От 3 до 15 символов!",
                            maxlength:"От 3 до 15 символов!"                               
      },
      "reg_patronymic":{
       required:"Укажите ваше Отчество!",
                            minlength:"От 3 до 25 символов!",
                            maxlength:"От 3 до 25 символов!"  
      },
      "reg_email":{
          required:"Укажите свой E-mail",
       email:"Не корректный E-mail"
      },
      "reg_phone":{
       required:"Укажите номер телефона!"
      },
      "reg_address":{
       required:"Необходимо указать адрес доставки!"
      },
      "reg_captcha":{
       required:"Введите код с картинки!",
                            remote: "Не верный код проверки!"
      }
     },
     
 submitHandler: function(form){
 $(form).ajaxSubmit({
 success: function(data) { 
         
        if (data == 'true')
    {
       $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300,function() {
        
        $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
        $("#form_submit").hide();
        
       });
         
    }
    else
    {
       $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data); 
    }
  } 
   }); 
   }
   });
     });
     
</script>
 <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block-body">
<?php
 include("include/block-header.php");
?>
<div id="block-right">
<?php
 include("include/block-category.php");
    include("include/block-parameter.php");
    include("include/block-news.php");
?>
</div>

<div id="block-content">

<h2 class="h2-title">Регистрация</h2>
<form method="post" id="form_reg" action="./reg/handler_reg.php">
<p id="reg_message"></p>
<div id="block-form-registration">
<ul id="form-registration">

<li>
<label>Логин</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_login" id="reg_login" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Пароль</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass" />
<span id="genpass">Сгенерировать</span>
</li>

<li>
<label>Фамилия</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_surname" id="reg_surname" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Имя</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_name" id="reg_name" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Отчество</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_patronymic" id="reg_patronymic" />
</li>

<li>
<label>E-mail</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_email" id="reg_email" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Мобильный телефон</label>
<span class="star" >*</span>
<input type="text" name="reg_phone" id="reg_phone" />
</li>

<li>
<label>Адрес доставки</label>
<span class="star" >*</span> 
<input type="text" name="reg_address" id="reg_address" />
</li>

<li>
<div id="block-captcha">

<img src="./reg/reg_captcha.php" />
<input type="text" name="reg_captcha" id="reg_captcha" />

<p id="reloadcaptcha">Обновить</p>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<p align="right"><input type="submit" name="reg_submit" id="form_submit" value="Регистрация" /></p>

</form>

</div>

<?php
 include("include/block-footer.php")
?>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

[image: вот собственно само сообщение при успешной регистрации, перечеркнула блок block-form-registration, который должен был вообще исчезнуть]

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у вас помимо чисто строки "true" возвращается что-то еще. Может быть пробелы или переносы строк.

В общем, не проходит проверка

```
if(data == 'true'){
```

Перепроверьте ответ от сервера, либо сделайте его в другом виде